# Does milvus auto-flush inserted data to object storage? or do we have to manually call flush?

Tags: database, vector, insert, milvus

I used the milvus1.x version in the past. After I insert data, I need to call the flush interface to ensure that the data is placed on the disk, so as to ensure that the newly inserted data can be searched. But when I used milvus2.0, I didn't find the flush() interface. Can Milvus 2.0 automatically flush newly inserted data now? Or do I have to call it manually too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not with the core dev team, but just confirmed  https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/discussions/27689

> All the milvus 2.x versions support automatic flush. Don't call flush() after each insert action.

Flushing data isn't necessary for it to be searched. Milvus does it brute-force.
Diving deeper, it seems milvus datanode has a buffer for 1024 rows, and flush will be automatically triggered if it's reached (or with some other conditions), and a new 1024-sized buffer will be allocated.